# How do C# derived Attributes work internally?When are the methods inside it called to act upon the class/method/property on which they are declared?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, custom-attributes

I was writing MVC code, where I used ValidationAttributes on the model , e.g - RequiredAttribute, RangeAttribute , etc. I just do not understand how these work internally. I have a CustomAttribute deriving from ValidationAttribute where IsValid was overridden and some custom check was made.When I put breakpoint on my CustomAttribute , it got called while updating the model , which makes sense. However I do not understand where the object gets passed to the Attribute. How and why is the Method called.

1.In Visual Studio I keep checking definitions of the Attributes, and there seems to be something missing. How is the object on which attribute is applied passed to the attribute class/object(is attribute object even instantiated?)
2.I went into my directory - C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7 and dragged System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll into justdecompile window. I do not see any implementations at all. IsValid has a blank body.

```
namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies that a data field value is required.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class RequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
        //     class.
        public RequiredAttribute();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value that indicates whether an empty string is allowed.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if an empty string is allowed; otherwise, false. The default value is false.
        public bool AllowEmptyStrings { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Checks that the value of the required data field is not empty.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   value:
        //     The data field value to validate.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if validation is successful; otherwise, false.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   T:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationException:
        //     The data field value was null.
        public override bool IsValid(object value);
    }
}
```

The above is from metadata when pressed F12 on Required attribute. Here IsValid has a value parameter. But there is no code which shows where its called or parameter is being passed.

What I would like to see as answer is a sample code snipped with maybe Required/Range/Conditional Attribute applied on a method/property(as applicable) and then step by step on when the Attribute actually does the work or if its not the attribute then where is the work done.

Comment: On further checking I dragged the mscorlib.dll into JustDecompile and saw this for IsValid method of Required attribute -  [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            string str = value as string;
            if (str == null || this.AllowEmptyStrings)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return str.Trim().Length != 0;
        } . It still does not answer give me the answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to the IsValid method is made automatically by the framework.
It searches in the class you specified for all attributes derived from ValidationAttribute using reflection and calls their IsValid method.

But this is a special case. If you make a custom attribute which is derived directly from Attribute you have to call it yourself.

You can search for the exact workflow in the source code of ASP.NET if you like: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack

Comment: But i though Required attribute has nothing to do with ASP.NET. it can even be applied on a class property in a Console application , right? What about Conditional Attribute?How does that work automatically?

Comment: Yes you can apply the attribute on a class proprty everywhere but then it does not get called automatically unless the framework you are using is aware of it. You can see the ValidationAttribute as general principle which has to be integrated into the framework to work automatically.

Comment: And the ConditionalAttribute is a litte different. The compiler checks the conditional attribute at compile time. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Can I see the source code somewhere of where it is integrated into the framework?

Comment: It is intergrated here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/749384689e027a2fcd29eb79a9137b94cea611a8/src/System.Web.WebPages/Validation/ValidationAttributeAdapter.cs which is used here:  https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/749384689e027a2fcd29eb79a9137b94cea611a8/src/System.Web.WebPages/Validation/Validator.cs

Comment: thanks for sharing the link, I will go through that code. Finally answer me this much so I can mark it as answer. I guess my question boils down to this - no matter what the attribute is , simply decorating it on a method/class/property wont do anything? and that is the case for Required/Range,etc as well?

Comment: Yes exacly. Attributes are only used to add additional information to something. It's up to you or a framework to handle this information and do something based on it.